# Trying to insert data manually into an Excel sheet and save the data when run the program

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I wrote a program with Python (pandas) that retrieve information from database and output into an Excel sheet.

This report is managed to help the team with different tasks and timelines.

I'm trying to add a functionality to a 'status' column to be able to add  to the column manually comments and have them not to be deleted in every program running.

```
Status

| 29/07/2021- add comment      
|
| 30/07/2021- comment 
|
|  001/08/2021 comment
```

For example:

[image]

What is the best way to do it ? there is a built in panda function?

Best regards

Comment: someone can help

Comment: Your question is not very clear which is why you have not received any answers. When you state that you are "trying to add a functionality to a 'status' column" what exactly do you want to add? And what have you coded so far?